# Blender FBX export is not rigging my bones correctly

Tags: armature, export, bones

I have this 3d model that has separate limbs as different objects, and all the bones are parented as "Bone" except for a few of them which are deform bones. I have an animation that's supposed to play

[image: Model Run Animation]

But when I Export it into an FBX, the animation is there but it only works on like 1 part of the model.

[image]

I've unchecked *Deform Bones Only* In the export many so that's not the issue. I don't know what could be causing this, I've messed with the settings a ton and nothing has happened. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you'll need to share your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.